# Hyperledger fabric client grpc deadline error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i am using fabric node js client to invoke the chaincode, I can query the chaincode, but when i am trying to submit the transaction, i am getting the error.

> fabric version 1.4.3
>
> using fabric client node js
>
> Failed to submit transaction: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://xx.xx.xxx:7050

In my connection json i have used the GRPC set keepalive_timeout_ms, but still i facing the error as mentioned above

```
"orderers": {
    "orderer.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://xx.xx.xx.xx:7050",

        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.example.com",
            "grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms":80000
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":"./fabric-node/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://xx.xx.xx.xx:7051",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms": 80000
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "./fabric-node/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fama
use below snippet but make sure is up and functioning `URL:grpcs://xx.xx.xxx:7050`

```
        "grpc-max-send-message-length": -1,
        "grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 600000,
        "grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms": 120000,
        "grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data": 0,
        "grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls": 1
```

Comment: thanks for replay, i solved it, but now i am facing the error: Endorsement has failed, when submitting the transaction. from cli its works i can submit the transaction, but from node js its through error: Endorsement has failed